# Google meet has no sound in Macbook chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, audio, macbook, google-meet

I can't hear other's voice. Even I selected the right audio device. I have no problem to play sound in chrome for other webside such as Youtube. There's no hardward problem or web brower permission problem.

Searched on the web, all of the radom answers, none of them solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your Google Meet?

Start your own session, and go to the Settings:

[image]

If you hear sound, the issue is the other side. If you do not hear sound, it's your own system.